# Wordpress with Infinite Scroll, Placing ads inbetween posts

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I've been stuck on this for a long time now, I'm wondering how would I go about placing a widget in between each 10 posts using  . The pagination being driven through Infinite Scroll. The plugin I am using is [ https://github.com/webcreate/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll ]. Any help would be fantastic, I have been stuck on this for awhile and my deadline is very soon.

```
<?php $postnum++; if($postnum%10 == 0) { ?>


<?php } ?>
```

This is what I have tried in the past.

Comment: Have you tried `for (every 10 posts) { put advert; }`

Comment: My apology I have tried using this method, when it is pulled back through infinite scroll it won't track 10 posts anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Loop

```
<?php $countpost = 0; ?>
```

Add this in your content loop.

```
<?php if ( (is_archive() or is_page() or is_search() or is_home()) && ($countpost == 0) ) : ?>

AD CODE HERE / Widget Code here

<?php
endif; 
$countpost++;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it. I just never played the postcount outside the loop!